# Split string with lookahead regex

Tags: regex, sumologic

I have this string:

```
{"TimePeriod": {"Start": "2017-03-01", "End": "2017-04-01"}, "Total": {"UnblendedCost": {"Amount": "2942.25119998", "Unit": "USD"}, "UsageQuantity": {"Amount": "20835", "Unit": "Hrs"}}, "Groups": [], "Estimated": false},
{"TimePeriod": {"Start": "2017-04-01", "End": "2017-05-01"}, "Total": {"UnblendedCost": {"Amount": "2982.62609983", "Unit": "USD"}, "UsageQuantity": {"Amount": "21049", "Unit": "Hrs"}}, "Groups": [], "Estimated": false},
{"TimePeriod": {"Start": "2017-05-01", "End": "2017-06-01"}, "Total": {"UnblendedCost": {"Amount": "1399.04829988", "Unit": "USD"}, "UsageQuantity": {"Amount": "23010", "Unit": "Hrs"}}, "Groups": [], "Estimated": false},
{"TimePeriod": {"Start": "2017-06-01", "End": "2017-07-01"}, "Total": {"UnblendedCost": {"Amount": "962.47549987", "Unit": "USD"}, "UsageQuantity": {"Amount": "20049", "Unit": "Hrs"}}, "Groups": [], "Estimated": false}
```

I am working on a regex to split the above string into multiple records, e.g: each record will look like:

```
{"TimePeriod": {"Start": "2017-06-01", "End": "2017-07-01"}, "Total": {"UnblendedCost": {"Amount": "962.47549987", "Unit": "USD"}, "UsageQuantity": {"Amount": "20049", "Unit": "Hrs"}}, "Groups": [], "Estimated": false}
```

My current approach is

```
(\{\"TimePeriod\":){1}.+(false\}){1}
```

But this will match the entire string instead of matching each record, I think the solution should be something with the lookahead in regex to ensure the **TimePeriod** appears just once in the matched string but I don't know how to do it. Any pointers will be appreciated.

*There is no newline between each line, I just put it there for the presentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems work for your need. I just only slightly changed your regex to `lazy` searching mode`.+?` from `greed` `.+`

```
(\{\"TimePeriod\":){1}.+?(false\}){1}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zuUjT4/8)

And if some more modification is added, it would be

```
(\{\"TimePeriod\":).+?(false\})
```

Another method using lookahead,

```
(\{\"TimePeriod\":)(?:(?!false).)+(false\})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may split on the following lookaround:

```
,(?=\{"TimePeriod":)
```

### Demo

The logic basically says to split at a point where there is a comma immediately followed by the text `{"TimePeriod":`.  Note that this means that there would not be a split at the very start of the text because there is no comma.

Comment: Hi Tim, is there anyway that we could eliminate the comma "," at the end of each line with regex? I am currently working with Sumologic, so there is no other way around rather than using regex

Comment: Tell me how you are using this regex.  Are you looking to do a replacement?

Comment: So in Sumologic, this string comes from a log file and I need to use a regex to split the string into multiple records in json format so that I could aggregate over them. You can read this for an example: https://support.sumologic.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206795357-Is-it-possible-to-split-a-JSON-list-into-multiple-records-

Comment: @Forrest I gave you an update which should meet your requirements.